# Highlight each column of a table

Tags: beamer

I created a simple table using a latex table generator. I want to highlight each of the columns in the table.

I want to add this table to the slides, I'm using the beamer documentclass this is my first time.

In the table I want to highlight in the 1st slide column x1.

2nd slide, column x2(without x1 highlighted)

3d slide column x3 (without x1 and x2 highlighted)

4th slide column x1 and x2

and so on.

Here is the script that I have which gives an error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{basileabeam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFCE93}}l |l|l|}
\hline
y & {\color[HTML]{333333} $x_1$} & $x_2$ & $x_3$ \\ \hline
5 & {\color[HTML]{333333} 3.3} & 2.1 & 4.1 \\ \hline
1.1 & {\color[HTML]{333333} 2.2} & 3.2 & 2.1 \\ \hline
2 & {\color[HTML]{333333} 5.1} & 8.1 & 2.2 \\ \hline
4 & {\color[HTML]{333333} 2.6} & 7 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here are the errors:

**! Undefined control sequence.**

**! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer} % <---
%\usepackage{basileabeam}     % <--- i don't have this package
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l| >{\columncolor[HTML]{FFCE93}\color{blue}}l |
            l|l|}
\hline
y   & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ \\ \hline
5   & 3.3   & 2.1   & 4.1   \\ \hline
1.1 & 2.2   & 3.2   & 2.1   \\ \hline
2   & 5.1   & 8.1   & 2.2   \\ \hline
4   & 2.6   & 7     & 1     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- For coloring table columns/rows instead of `usepackage{xcolor}` you had to load `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.
- `beamer` already load `xcolor` package, so you need only ad option `table` to `beamer` document class options (as is done in MWE above).

Comment: @Ville, i make attention only to your mwe :-(. do you like to have change row color from slide to slide? is this is case, i can further help you at evening ...

Comment: to highlight each of the columns should I create in each slide a table with a different column highlighted and in the end connect them somehow together

Comment: yes I just want to be able to change the colors of each column. I want to show them in one slide actually so that first the x1 column is highlighted then the next and so on. I'm not sure if I have to create many slides and then connect them together to one so that the highlight would take effect. I have time just write when you are available. Thank you :)